# ASP.NET : saving changes not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET project. When I am trying to save the changes for the asset of the machine name, the project says update successful, but when i refresh the page the machine name was not saved. Here is some of the code.

The controller

```
private void UpdatePartAsset(ICollection<PartAsset> collection, int partId)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        item.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
        item.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
        item.PartId = partId;

        if (item.Id == 0)
        {
            db.PartAssets.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            var asset = db.PartAssets.Find(item.Id);

            if (item.Deleted)
            {
                db.PartAssets.Remove(asset);
            }
            else
            {
                asset.PartId = item.PartId;
                asset.AssetId = item.AssetId;
                asset.LastModified = item.LastModified;
                asset.UserName = item.UserName;
            }
        }
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `Find` method try single method `var asset = db.PartAssets.Single(item.Id);`

Comment: @MohsinMehmood: why? What's wrong with `.Find()` ??

Comment: Do both the database and page not show the changes?

Comment: if i use Single it comes up with an error "Cannot convert from int"

Comment: Sorry try like this: `var asset = db.PartAssets.Single(i=>i.Id == item.Id);`

Comment: for some reason now i am getting the error System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.' 
     @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        @Html.Action("UserRoles", "Home")
    }

Comment: thanks @MohsinMehmood that helped

Comment: @marc_s I think the entity returned by `Find` is in detached state and changes made to this entity are not tracked. But I am not sure.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities